# How do I describe this chord (A in bass with F# upper structure triad)?

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-theory, jazz, chord-voicings

I'm trying to expand my harmony (past the 7ths/9ths/sus4 which have served me fine for pop), and I constructed something funky.  I never really got into chord vocab, so I don't know how to describe it so I can explore it more.

From the bottom up, it's: A E F# Bb C# (E)

I think it's A-something.  Or is that F# actually a Gb, like a diminished 7th?  In the model I was testing, the Bb would actually be an A# but that definitely seems unlikely.

I'm using it like this ([link with audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us76b.jpg)):

- G6 (G D E G B)
- A??? (A E F# Bb C#)
- Bm9 (B F# A C# D)

Thanks!

Comment: To get a definitive answer, we'd need the chord in a context. The notes by themselves could be interpreted several ways, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: @Aaron: I only got as far as the three chord sequence I posted in the question, but it feels pretty strongly like B minor to me.

Comment: I've added a link to a video with audio, for a clearer idea.

Comment: How about describing it in terms of actual music, not verbally. Your example goes to a B minor chord after this chord X, but where else could it plausibly go? Could it go to a D major? D _minor_? The chord opens up some possibilities and maybe closes some possibilities. How do you feel about it? If you play an A half-whole diminished scale over it, does that feel like preserving the original chord's nature? In what other songs and what roles in them can you place this chord X, while serving essentially the same purpose? How does chord X change the situation compared to the original chords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying harmony is A7 (♮13 ♭9), which could also be notated more simply as A13♭9 (the notation A13 implies that the 7th is flatted). In context, the progression is: `| GMaj | A13♭9 | Bmin |` and the A13♭9 to Bmin creates a false cadence. The chords `| GMaj | A13♭9 |` want to resolve to DMaj, which would create the highly common IV-V-I progression. But instead, the progression resolves to Bmin, the iv chord--and Bmin is the relative minor to DMaj.

Regarding the way you've voiced A13♭9: the F♯ Maj triad that occurs in the right hand is called an "upper structure triad." For a dominant seventh chord, there are tons of upper structure triads that fit squarely within traditional jazz theory. You can play 1-3-7 in the left hand (A-C♯-G) and simultaneously play any of the following upper structure triads in your right hand:

- F♯ Maj - creates A13♭9
- B Maj - creates A13♯11
- F Maj - creates A7(♯9♭13)
- E♭ Maj - creates A7(♭5♭9)
- B♭ min - creates A7(♭9♭13)

The voicing you've used for A13♭9 doesn't contain the flatted 7th (a G). The G would often be included in the chord voicing for A13♭9, but certainly not always. But if you intended for this chord to **never** be voiced with any 7th, then you would notate it Aadd13♭9.

Comment: There is no G in the chord, it is not a dominant chord.

Comment: @ggcg, if a jazz guitarist or pianist sees the chord A13(b9) in a chart, no one expects them to include a G in every single chord they use to comp over the A13(b9). So I think your criteria that "it's only A7b9 if it contains a G" goes against how jazz musicians actually play and voice chords.

Comment: @jdjazz I'd change "This chord _is_ A7 (♮13 ♭9)"  to something like: the chord can be felt as performing the same role as what an A7 would do ... as well as some other roles, for example an F#.

Comment: @ggcg You don't need a G note. I guess you knew that already, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominant_(music) "In music, the dominant is the fifth scale degree of the diatonic scale." and "The triad built on the dominant note is called the dominant chord." In the context (the video) the chord sounds like a mixture between A major and F# major, leaving both options plausible, either going to B something or D something next. Harmonic expectations are imagined by a listener, which is why descriptions (such as yours) contain things you subjectively expected, not only actually sounding notes.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica your point about the phrasing is well-taken. How about I change "This chord is..." to "The harmony here is..."?

Comment: By definition the chord name indicates the structure.  No one is saying that this is the dominant of the scale, i.e. the V, they are all saying this is a 13th chord, which is by definition (1, 3, 5, b7, 9, 11, 13).

Comment: @ggcg Thinking of it as a 13 with the 7th left out is not far off, because in the given context, the point of the chord is to do a V of some kind possibly heading towards D ... but with a twist, eventually ending up in Bm. If the song had "A7" written at that point, you might play this chord instead and it would sound nice and do the job of an A7 at that point, even without a G note. A nice guitar fingering/voicing for this is x0x322. You can add a G: x05322 and then it sounds even fuller, but maybe more stereotypical? IMO the G is not required there. Would F#7/A be more understandable?

Comment: As a compromise, how about calling it Aadd(b9,13)?

Comment: @Aaron, I tend to think that Aadd(b9,13) would be leaving something out of the description of the harmony. If one were to include the 7th, they would want to include the flatted 7th rather than the natural 7th, and A13(b9) conveys this. I think the way to approach the question "what chord is this" is to provide the true underlying harmony. I think this is a more flexible approach that makes room for multiple different voicings for a single underlying chord. Sometimes you include the b7, and sometimes you don't. That's how jazz is played, in practice.

Comment: @Aaron, I was thinking more about what you said. There may be circumstances where the composer never wants the 7th to be voiced. In that case, your notation would make good sense. I've added a sentence at the end about that.

Comment: We're in sync. IMO, your answer covers all the bases well.

Comment: This question and the answers and the discussion in the comments... deep, but unfortunately the StackExchange site format doesn't acknowledge such ambiguity. The OP has basically layered pieces of two "dominant" chords of relative keys, as in "V chords", on top of each other ... this reminds me of Barry Harris and the diminished scale and that the V chords of relative keys are kind of the same. There are many perspectives, and all of them are kind of like true at the same time. That's how MUSIC works. But that's not how StackExchange wants things to be like.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

In the key of A, you have C# = Maj 3rd, E = 5th, so you have an A maj triad.

The F# is the 6th, and the Bb a flat 9th.  It's an odd one.  If the dom 7th were there I'd lean towards a 13 (b9).  But the A does NOT have to be the tonic.

Starting from F# I would tread the Bb as enharmonic with A#.  And I'd treat the A as enharmonic with the Gx (double sharp).

Now you have (F#, A#(Bb), C#) as an F# maj triad.  E is the dom 7th and A the #9.  So this could be thought of as a strange voicing of an F#(#9),

(1, 3, 5, b7, #9) = (F#, A#, C#, E, Gx).  That is not consistent with how you have spelled it, I'd get points off on a theory test for doing this probably, but the fact is in a 12TET tuning system like piano or guitar you will hear a #9 chord.

Comment: So you reckon it's an F#(#9)... 4th inversion?

Comment: In the video, he's doubling the A with the left hand. To me, that rules out F#(#9). Putting the #9 in the bass causes that note to sound like a b3 and not a #9, which is why this practice is almost never used. That makes F#(#9)/A a highly unlikely choice for the chord. To me, this is a clear case of A13b9, voiced with an upper structure triad (F# Maj). The b7 is missing, but changing the left hand from A2-A3 to A2-G2 completes the sound and completes the voicing, which to me is further evidence that this is indeed A13b9.

Comment: I didn't see any video but (1) A13(b9) was my first choice, (2) I disagree with your analysis on doubling notes and placement of the 9th in the bass.  Guitar voicings use this all the time, a 4th inversion is not illegal.  Perhaps, as you point out not typical but not at all wrong.  I would also say that the 7th can NOT be ignored in a 13th chord.

Comment: @ggcg, if you haven't seen the video, then what I'm saying may not make sense. This is a piano voicing, not a guitar voicing, and the left hand is representing what a *bassist* would play, not what a chordal instrument would play. No straight-ahead jazz bassist would sustain the #9 for the entirety of a dominant 7th #9 chord--this doesn't happen ever in straight-ahead jazz. From lowest to highest, the notes are A2-A3-F#3-A#4-C#4.

Comment: @ggcg, just to clarify: when I say "putting the #9 in the bass," I'm literally talking about the bass player, not a chordal guitar voicing which is played on top of some other bass note.

Comment: There was no video when I answered.

Comment: @jdjazz, why can't the bass player play  the #9?  That makes no sense at all.  Depending on the other chords the bass may decide to play and descending or ascending scale pattern through the chords.  That makes less sense than the guitarist opting not to play it.

Comment: Yeah, I added the video later, because a comment asked for more context.  Sorry, @gcgg!  There were some differences I thought were not relevant (e.g. doubling the bass) because it sounded the same to me as my original construction.

Comment: @ggcg, have you had a chance yet to watch the video? Context is everything. This is a slow song and the #9 is doubled and sustained for the entirety of the chord. I didn't say bass players can't play the #9--I'm not talking about theoretical rules here. I'm saying it just doesn't happen; bassists don't sustain the #9 over the entire dominant chord in a straight-ahead jazz context.

Comment: Probably, they don't do it for the same reason that they don't sustain the natural 7th over a dominant 7th chord: the notes that define the dominant 7th chord are the 3rd and 7th, and the b3 is the same as the #9, and so a bassist sustaining a #9 would be indistinguishable from a bassist sustaining a b3 (an incorrect note). Why would someone hear the #9 and the bass and mistake it for a b3? Most bass lines emphasize the 1 and 5, as well as the 3 and 7 (which define the chord quality). This is why, if a bassist were to play the #9 that low for that long, then it would conflict with the harmony.

Comment: This sounds like "Welcome to Jazz -101".

Comment: @ggcg, which sounds more like a Jazz 101 lesson: (1) an A13 chord *must* be voiced with the flatted 7th; if it doesn't contain a G, then it's not an A13 chord. Or: (2) bassists don't sustain the #9 over the full duration of a dom7 chord because emphasizing an altered upper extension that is enharmonically equivalent to the b3 can cause cast doubt in the listener's ear about the chord quality. Between the two, "rule" #1 is waaaaay more likely to be broken. I've also never seen #2 written down--it's based on what we hear when we listen to straight-ahead jazz.

Comment: I said -101.  To indicate that this is anti jazz, or anti music theory.  Definitions exist for a reason.  By definition a 13th chord has the b.  I didn't invent that, it is what it is.

Comment: I cannot imagine how you come to these rules or anti rules.  You have no right to tell the bassist what to do and "causing doubt in the listener's mind" is what music and art is all about.  The great ones do what most people won't and still make it work.  Listen.

Comment: @ggcg, I ask this sincerely--can you link to a single instance of a great bassist sustaining the #9 for the entire duration of the dom7 chord? I don't think I've ever heard this. I've done a lot of transcribing and I've listened to a lot of music, but I've certainly not heard every jazz recording. But this gets to my broader point--I'm afraid you've misread. I'm not articulating "rules" or telling bassists what they can play. I'm simply describing what they *actually* play, as evidenced by every straight-ahead jazz recording that exists. Bassists don't play a #9 over the full dom7 chord.

Comment: @ggcg, and I'm not trying to be cheeky--I really would be very interested to hear a #9 sustained in the bass over the entire duration of a dom7 chord. I'd be interested in hearing how it's used. But its apparent rarity makes me think that great bassists don't do it because they think it doesn't sound good. That doesn't qualify it as a "rule"--it's just means it's a widely held consensus by great bassists about what sounds good in the music.

Comment: @ggcg, one final thought--I don't want to beat a dead horse. I really think our disagreement was due to context. I was answering entirely within the context of the video he shared, which I know didn't exist when you posted. cloudfeet and I both seemed to misinterpret the final sentence of your post as saying that your first choice is F#(#9). The idea of #9 in the bass is one I'll definitely be thinking about more.